# TypeError in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

I'm having trouble with some code, where I have a text file with 633,986 tuples, each with 3 values (example: the first line is `-0.70,0.34,1.05`). I want to create an array where I take the magnitude of the 3 values in the tuple, so for elements `a,b,c`, I want `magnitude = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)`.

However, I'm getting an error in my code. Any advice?

```
import math
fname = '\\pathname\\GerrysTenHz.txt'
open(fname, 'r')

Magn1 = [];
for i in range(0, 633986):
    Magn1[i] = math.sqrt((fname[i,0])^2 + (fname[i,1])^2 + (fname[i,2])^2)

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: You are not reading the file. `open(fname, 'r')` **returns** a new open file object, which you ignore. You are not reading from that open file object. What do you expect `fname[i, 0]`, etc. to give you? That is not valid Python (or rather, it is, but not doing what you expect it to do, `i, 0` is seen as a tuple, hence the exception).

Comment: The exponentiation operator is also `**` not `^`. `x=2**3` sets `x` to `8`.

Comment: And `^` is the XOR operator, not the exponent operator (`**`).

Comment: Last but not least, you can drop the `;` semi-colons.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was expecting fname[i,0] to give me the 1st number in the tuple on the ith row, although I'm guessing that's not correct.

Comment: @AndrewM: `fname` is still a string. Even if it was an [open file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), you still need to *read* from that file object. File objects do not act like sequences, let alone multidimensional ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the lines of the file and the `csv` module (as Martijn Pieters points out) to examine each value.  This can be done with a list comprehension and `with`:

```
with open(fname) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        magn1 = [math.sqrt(sum(float(i)**2 for i in row)) for row in reader]
```

just make sure you `import csv` as well

---

To explain the issues your having (there are quite a few) I'll walk through a more drawn out way to do this.

you need to use what `open`returns.  `open` takes a string and returns a file object.

```
f = open(fname)
```

I'm assuming the range in your for loop is suppose to be the number of lines in the file.  You can instead iterate over each line of the file one by one

```
for line in f:
```

Then to get the numbers on each line, use the `str.split` method of to split the line on the commas

```
    x, y, z = line.split(',')
```

convert all three to `float`s so you can do math with them

```
    x, y, z = float(x), float(y), float(z)
```

Then use the `**` operator to raise to a power, and take the sqrt of the sum of the three numbers.

```
    n = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
```

Finally use the `append` method to add to the back of the list

```
    Magn1.append(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file properly (use the open file object and the `csv` module to parse the comma-separated values), read each row and convert the strings into `float` numbers, then apply the correct formula:

```
import math, csv

fname = '\\pathname\\GerrysTenHz.txt'
magn1 = []

with open(fname, 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    for row in reader:
        magn1.append(math.sqrt(sum(float(c) ** 2 for c in row)))
```

which can be simplified with a list comprehension to:

```
import math, csv

fname = '\\pathname\\GerrysTenHz.txt'

with open(fname, 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    magn1 = [math.sqrt(sum(float(c) ** 2 for c in row)) for row in reader]
```

The `with` statement assigns the open file object to `inputfile` and makes sure it is closed again when the code block is done.

We add up the squares of the column values with `sum()`, which is fed a generator expression that converts each column to `float()` before squaring it.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at `fname`. That's a string. So if you try to subscript it (i.e., `fname[i, 0]`), you should use an integer, and you'll get back the character at index `i`. Since you're using `[i, 0]` as the string indices, you're passing a tuple. That's no integer!

Really, you should be reading a line from the file, then doing things with that. So,

```
with(open(fname, 'r')) as f: # You're also opening the file and doing nothing with it
    for line in f:
        print('doing something with %s' % line)
```